# Video.js attach black border on video

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use video.js in my application for display custom videos. It is working fine but the problem is related to its style, when video displays a black border on its left and right side appears. That means video is not displaying on its full window.

Comment: Please provide code samples

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen your code, but it seems like the container for the video element is not an exact fit for your video.

Perhaps your container width-to-height ratio needs to match the video you are trying to display, otherwise if the borders only appear black on the left-right, then the video containers height is too small and should be larger.

Comment: i set both on auto , height and width code is too much lengthy that's y i am unable to paste here i think u r right but how can i detect the right height and width for ipad ??